# Patch request with angular.js is send to wrong url

Tags: angularjs

My REST API is configured to accept this kind of request

```
public function lockUserAction($slug)
{} // "lock_user"     [PATCH] /users/{slug}/lock
```

So sending a patch request to

```
/api/users/2/lock
```

Will lock the user with id=2. This is my rest service inside angular.js

```
angular.module('UserService',['ngResource']).factory('User', function($resource){
    var User = $resource('/api/users/:id',
        {},
        { 
          list: { method: 'GET' },
          lock: { method: 'PATCH' }
        }
    );   
    return User;
});
```

List works just finde, but lock does not work. The console prints:

```
PATCH /api/users 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

I invoke it like this

```
$scope.lock = function(user){
    user.$lock();
}
```

In the error message I see the url `/api/users` instead of `/api/users/2/lock`. Is this normal behaviour? Of course list excepts only GET requests and PATCH requests are not allowed on `/api/users` only on `/api/users/{slug}/lock`.

Any ideas why /api/users is called and not /api/users/{slug}/lock. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Patch? You're making up your own HTTP verbs? That's fine, but see what's happening on your server side. For some reason it's returning a 405 error for these requests. Make sure the incoming URL has the :id param in it for one thing.

Comment: @darkporter http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5789

Comment: @darkporter I do not make my own HTTP verbs. I use FOSRestBundle in backend which uses PATCH. Yes, but it seems that the wrong URL is called.

Comment: never seen `PATCH` used for ajax requests... inspect actual request in browser console or fiddler and see what method is being sent, and what url is being used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `$lock` angular has no idea that you intend to call the same url as before, with some extra path element. Also there is no way for angular to know what is a value of `:id` param.

Than let angular know about locking:

```
var User = $resource('/api/users/:id/:action', //add param to the url
        {}, 
        { 
          list: { method: 'GET' },
          lock: { method: 'PATCH',params:{action:"lock",id:"@id"}} //set param value, so angular knows where to send request, @id refers to user id in json representation of user
        }
    );
```

Comment: You answer before the edit worked partially, it was missing the action parameter in the called url (/api/users/2 405 (Method Not Allowed) ). Your current answer has the same problem like in my question. I get again /api/users 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Comment: Sorry, I had one more typo , instead of parameters there should be a param key, I've tried the code and it should be working. The only problem can be with '@id' value, because I'm not sure what is the name of property in your user project